# Analyze Admob banners coming to an Android app

Tags: android, admob

Is there a way to analyze admob banners coming to my Android app?
I want to get the 'Add source','time', 'category' etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am integrate admob network in many apps.But i can't find out analyzer to relevant ad.

You can set your `time to refresh` the ad.Because google is provided manually ad.

Answer (score 0):

Other than time (which you can get the from the time the ad gets to your AdListener) The answer is no.